# Update nested structure by list of subfields

Tags: matlab, struct, eval

And another episode of today's "Fun with structs", this one is a tough one.
I'd like to create a nested structure dynamically by a given list of subfields of arbitary length, like in the following example:

```
x = 42;
a.e = struct;
subfields = {'b','c','d'}; %// arbitary length!

%// desired result
a.b.c.d = x;
```

**How can that be done?**

---

Of course there is an evil `eval` solution, but I try to avoid to be evil.

```
evalexp = ['a' cellfun(@(s) ['.' s], subfields, 'uni',0)];
evalexp = [evalexp{:}];
eval( [evalexp '= x'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`setfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html):

```
x = 42;
a.e = struct;
subfields = {'b','c','d'};

a = setfield(a, subfields{:}, x);
```

Which returns:

```
>> a.b.c.d

ans =

    42
```

Comment: This is likely the best answer. But you should avoid destroying original struct a.

Comment: you are right. When I saw 'a' alone is at left side of equal sign, I assume original content is destroyed :)

Answer (score 3):

```
aa = x;
for i = numel(subfields):-1:2
    aa = struct(subfields{i}, aa);
end
a.(subfields{1}) = aa;
```

I hope for loop is not forbidden :)

Comment: This is actually great backwards thinking! But you destroy the original struct `a`, which is a big issue. Just imagine `a` has much more fields and subfields, which should remain untouched. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Good point. Just updated the answer accordingly by introducing a temp variable.